# Tratamento de Erro para violação de chave estrangeira-java-postgreSql

Tags: java

Criei uma tabela *matricula*, e 5 tabelas de materias, as duas são ligadas por chave estrangeira, e dentro do meu programa tem uma tela para simular uma matricula de um aluno, onde um dos passos é escolher as disciplinas, podendo escolher no máximo 5 e no minimo uma. Porem não estou conseguindo fazer o devido tratamento de erro para quando escolhe-se de primeira, q4 matérias.

Segue o tratamento no código:

```
if(jComboBoxMateria1.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && jComboBoxMateria2.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && jComboBoxMateria3.getSelectedIndex() == 0 &&
                    jComboBoxMateria4.getSelectedIndex() == 0 && jComboBoxMateria5.getSelectedIndex() == 0){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "É Necessário escolher ao menos 1 Matéria para efetuar a Matricula");
                return;
            }
```

Porem se eu não seleciono as 5 materias, ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

> "Erro ao executar comando SQLERRO: inserção ou atualização em tabéla
>   matricula viola restrição de chave estrangeira"

Creio que o erro aconteça pois na tabela matricula possui os 5 campos com chave estrangeira das materias, que de fato conforme as tabelas deveriam serem todos preenchido. O que eu poderia fazer é trocar o && por || e dizer que é necessário escolher 5 materias, porem não simularia um cenário real.

Como posso fazer esse tratamento para que escolhendo ao menos uma materia ja seja possivel fazer a matricula?

Comment: Te apresento [`JCheckBox`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html#checkbox). Faz bem mais sentido usar esse componente, assim, você valida somente se tiver ao menos um item checado. Veja um [exemplo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10045418/5524514)

Comment: Poste a DDL de suas tabelas também, se suas FK estiverem como not null na tabela matricula, você terá que informar os 5 campos, senão não irá conseguir gravar.

Comment: Acredito que há um erro na sua lógica de banco. Imagino que a relação entre matricula e materia seja nxn, ou seja, podem existir materias com 0 ou n matriculas, e vice-versa. Logo, precisaria de uma tabela auxiliar para fazer esta relação. Chave estrangeira se usa quando a relação é 1xn, a tabela n é a que terá uma chave estrangeira.

Comment: Diego, realmente eu ainda não conhecia o componente jCheckBox, dei uma olhada no exemplo, obrigado.

Comment: Geferson, Realmente. a FK estavam como not null, ai estava um dos erros...valeu

Comment: Diego, referente a a lógica do banco, realmente sou iniciante em questão de BD, mas as tabelas não eram nxn, o que aconteceu foi que criei 5 tabélas aonde em uma ja era o suficiente, pois as 5 tabélas de matérias tinham as mesmas matérias nas 5, mas consegui resolver o problema, ja estou me aprofundando mais aqui na questão de relacionamento entre tabélas, valeu pela força

Comment: Já verifiquei em vários sites, inclusive internacionais, para obter a resposta de como tratar este erro. Mas felizmente encontrei de forma bem simples neste link: **http://javafree.uol.com.br/topic-883230-Ajuda-com-violacao-de-chave-estrangeira.html.** Espero que ajude a todos.